# A generic queue with reference data types

Tags: java

I have implemented a generic queue (in java) that works fine with different data types however I get "out of bounds" error from the compiler when I try to instantiate my queue with reference types like; `Queue<Node<T>> myQueue = new Queue<Node<T>>();`
This is part of my implementation:

```
public class Queue<F extends Comparable<? super F>>
{
    private static class QueueNode<F extends Comparable<? super F>>
    {
        private F data;
    private QueueNode<F> next;

    public QueueNode()
    {
        next = null;
    }
    public QueueNode(F val)
    {
        data = val;
        next = null;
    }
    }
    private QueueNode<T> head, rear;
    public Queue()
    {
        head = rear = null;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
    }
    public void enqueue(F el)
    {
    }
    public F dequeue()
    {
    } 
}
```

I have a Binary Tree that was implemented in terms of Node and this queue is to be used in one of the methods in Binary Tree class. Can anyone please help me spot out the problem and solve it!
Ok, this is exactly what the compiler says:
Queue> myQueue = new Queue>();
"type argument Node is not within bounds of type variable F"
"where T, F are typ-variable:
     T extends Comparable declared in class BinarySearchTree
     F extends Comparable declared in class Queue"

Comment: What is the exact compiler error message?  Please add it to your question.

Comment: does `Node<T>` extend `Comparable<Node<T>>`?

Comment: As long as `T` is no actual class, you cannot define a `Queue` like that (outside of the class itself). `T` must be replaced with a _real_ class. Is `Node` generic? If not, `Queue<Node> myQueue = new Queue<Node>();` should be just fine.

Comment: And you might want to look at the [JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) and use an out-of-the-box `Queue`.

Answer (score 0):

`myQueue` declaration should use an actual class instead of `T`.

Ex: To create a queue of `String`

```
Queue<Node<String>> myQueue = new Queue<Node<String>>();
```